# How to get the values from XML file and bind the values in the HTML page dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the Data from XML file and Bind the values in the HTML page dynamically using jQuery?

**Input :**

```
<Channel ID="1">
    <Program Name ="A">XYG</Program>
    <Program Name ="B">ABC</Program>    
</Channel>
<Channel ID="2">
    <Program Name ="A">QQQ</Program>    
</Channel>
```

Output: HTML page with `div` tags

```
|Channel 1| |XYG | |ABC|

|Channel 2| |    QQQ   |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Simply review the jQuery documentation for parsing XML documents and you will understand.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/